# Create a 3D numpy array with a loop from multiple 2D images

Tags: numpy

I want to read from many sample images, and make 2D numpy array that row "i" corresponds to i'th sample, and column j correspond to j'th pixel of image(all pixels of a 12*13 image is saved by a list of 156 numbers)

```
import numpy as np
images = np.array([])
for Letter in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO":
    im = Image.open("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO\\16\\"+Letter+".bmp")
    sampleimage = list(im.getdata())
    images = np.append(images,[sampleimage])
```

however I struggling making 2D numpy array. above "images" array become an (1800,) array insted of (11,156) . I tried many differend ways but none of them working properly or efficient (making 2D python list and then converting to numpy array is not efficient. although even that solution doesn't work).

so my question is, what is the best way of creating a 2D numpy array on the fly?

Comment: `np.append` is hard to use correctly, and even then is slow.  Reread the `np.append` docs.  Without an `axis` parameter it flattens the inputs, hence your result.

Answer (score 1):

You are treating the numpy array `images` like an list.
Have a look at [numpy.stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html). But in my memory the fastest way is to convert each image to an numpy array, aggregate them in a list and then turn the list into an array.

```
import numpy as np
images = list()
for Letter in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO":
    im = Image.open("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO\\16\\"+Letter+".bmp")
    sampleimage = np.array(im.getdata())
    images.append(sampleimage)
images_array = np.array(images)
```

In your case the resulting array should have the size `[1800,11,156]` or `[11,156,1800]`